# Another Way to use Dispatcher.CheckAccess?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I am new to WPF.

CODE 1:

```
      if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {

                if (ab == "abc")
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke( () =>
                    lab1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

                    , DispatcherPriority.Normal);

                }
            }
```

here in the above code i just want to change the visibility on Label.

But with multiple changes like this ....

CODE 2 :

```
      if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {

                if (ab == "abc")
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke( () =>
                    lab1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

                    lab2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden

                    lab3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden

                    , DispatcherPriority.Normal);

                }
            }
```

its not working , so Can anyone help me out how to Invoke multiple instances ?

Comment: Use `{ ... }` in the Lambda

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( () =>
     {
         lab1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         lab2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
         lab3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     } , DispatcherPriority.Normal) );`

Comment: Opps :D m so lame :D thankz @Lambda so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your code isn't compiling. You should change your dispatcher todo this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( () =>
     {
         lab1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         lab2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
         lab3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
     } ) );
```

The `Dispatcher` is used to dispatch items from different threads onto the UI thread. `CheckAccess()` will check to see if you are on the `Dispatcher` thread (or UI thread). If you already are, it will not go into your if statement. Are you absolutely sure that you already aren't on the `Dispatcher` thread?

Comment: thankz for the answer it worked . yea i am sure but il use if() else() to avoid and error.